# Declare multiple integer variables in C

Tags: c, syntax

Before i start, I am not good at English so I use a translator, so you may not understand well.

I'm so sorry. But the content of the question is easy, so there is probably no difficulty understanding.

One day I don't remember very well, but I saw a code similar to the one below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
int a,b,c = 1,d,e;
return 0;
}
```

At that time, I just let it go. But now that I think about it, I'm curious.
So I checked the value of C, and it was printed 1.

And I changed 1 to 0 and confirmed that the value of C was zero.

This result was the same for the other numbers.

I've never seen a code like this before.

In the meantime, I knew that to declare a number of variables, I would have to do as the code below.

`int a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;`
But it wasn't what I knew.

After several experiments, I found that a,b,c,d,e were independent variables.

Except for C, a,b,d,e contained garbage value.

I wonder why this is grammatically possible and why the values are not allocated in order from left to right.

Once again, I'm sorry for using the translator.

Comment: The thing is that you can declare the variables and then initialize whichever variable you want. There is no grammatical rule for initializing from left to right.

Comment: ; is a punctuator that finishes the assignment or initialization while declaring variables. It is valid to declare multiple variables before ;.

Comment: OMG It was a really simple thing. Thank you guys very much !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int a,b,c = 1,d,e;
```

is the same as

```
int a;
int b;
int c = 1;
int d;
int e;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Except for C, a,b,d,e contained garbage value** - This is because only C is both declared and initialized with the value 1. Others are just declared in a random memory location, hence has garbage values

**I wonder why this is grammatically possible** - It is a right syntax still. See the answer by @pmg

**In the meantime, I knew that to declare a number of variables, I would have to do as the code below. `int a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;`** - Here you are actually declaring as well as initializing them with different values. You can always declare any number of variables (of the same datatype) in a single statement.

Comment: Thank you! I thought the left and right sides were different based on the equal sign!